# Understanding the difference between `load`, `require`, and `require_relative`

Tags: ruby

I do not understand the difference between the three methods of importing library or module. As I currently understand it,

```
load 'file.rb'
```

would import the contents of the external file into the current file whereas:

```
require 'file.rb'
```

would perform the same functionality but would not import a file that had already been imported.

```
require_relative 'file.rb'
```

is similar to `require`, but it will load a file that is only in the current directory whereas `require` will use the search path `$:` in an effort to find the file. I have no doubt my understanding of the three mechanisms is flawed. Could anyone offer some clarification?

Comment: that's pretty much it. require_relative is relative to the current file locations. load always load, require just the first time.

Comment: You may like to go through this as well:- http://ionrails.com/2009/09/19/ruby_require-vs-load-vs-include-vs-extend/

Comment: In RSpec, why does running "load 'Rakefile`" work but "require 'Rakefile'" does not work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`load` is used when you want to import a file irrespective of whether it has been already imported. `require` or `require_relative` is used when you want to import a file only if it has not been already.

From this, it follows that the former is used when the imported file is the object of analysis (data file), whereas the latter is used to provide some features to be used in the program (part of the program, library, framework).

While `require` can only handle paths relative to `$:`, `require_relative` is an extension that can handle paths relative to current directory as well. `require_relative` is a superset of `require`, and `require` can be dispensed (although `require_relative` is written using `require`, so it has to be rewritten if `require` is to be dispensed).

Comment: In RSpec, why does running "load 'Rakefile`" work but "require 'Rakefile'" does not work?