# Difference between require and load wrt to "load" and "execute"

Tags: ruby

Below are some snippets from the documentation for `Kernel`:

[Kernel#load](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Kernel.html#method-i-load)

> Loads and executes the Ruby program in the file filename...

[Kernel#require](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Kernel.html#method-i-require)

> Loads the given name...

I know there are differences between `require` and `load` for example:

- `require` will tack on an `rb` extension while `load` will not
- `require` will store the ruby file path inside `$LOADED_FEATURES` aka `$"` while `load` will not
- `require` will search `$LOADED_FEATURES` before "loading" the file again while `load` will not

I'm wondering about the distinction between the word "load" and the word "executes".

The documentation makes it seem like they are two different things. To me, "load" would mean "Hey I know about this file now" while "execute" would mean "Hey I know about this file now and I'm going to run all the commands also"

But I don't think that's right.

For example, given the following structure:

```
$  tree
.
├── bar.rb
├── baz.rb
└── foo.rb

0 directories, 3 files
```

with foo.rb:

```
$LOAD_PATH << __dir__
require 'bar'
load 'baz.rb'
```

bar.rb:

```
puts "Inside of bar..."
```

baz.rb:

```
puts "Inside of baz..."
```

When I run `foo.rb` I would expect "Inside of baz..." to print but not "Inside of bar..." because `load` "loads and executes" while `require` just "loads". But what actually happens is both seem to "execute":

```
$  ruby foo.rb
Inside of bar...
Inside of baz...
```

So is there a difference between "loading" and "executing" a ruby file?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34407955

Comment: How does that post explain the difference between "loading" a file and "executing" a file?

Comment: Is there any reason `Kenel#load` would mention both?

Comment: See the bit I added to the end of my previous comment.  I messed up a quote, so here it is again: There's no difference between 'load' and "execute"--as your example illustrates, they both execute the code in the file, which creates constants(e.g. class names) and outputs messages.  You could interpret the docs to be saying `load = loads + executes`  and `require = loads` therefore `require = loads + executes`.  But generally, the ruby docs can be pretty bad.

Comment: So do you think the "load" in `Kernel#require` is referring to `Kernel#load` while the "load" in `Kenrnel#load` is referring to the act of loading the file in memory but not executing the commands?

Comment: Code has to be loaded before it can be executed.  Unfortunately, that distinction is not necessary to explain what load does and what require does.  They both execute the code.  The main difference between them is that `require` will not re-excute a file when it is required again, where `load` will, so if some dynamic changes occurred to the file that was required, require will not see those changes, while load will execute the file anew so any changes will be executed.

Comment: For example, if the file that was required has the line `puts "hello"`, and the file was changed to read `puts "goodbye"`, and thereafter some code re-required that same file, there would be no additional output.  On the other hand if the file were load()'ed again, you would see the new output.  Or, even more basic: even if the file weren't changed load() would produce the same output again, while require wouldn't.  Try it with your example.

Comment: Also, it seems like `load` will only load and execute files as Ruby files while `require` will load and execute Ruby files but also “.so”, “.o”, or “.dll” files. Is that right?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know.  The following seems to support what you say: http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/including_other_files_in_ruby.html -- ... this bareword way of referring to the extension is necessary because not all extensions use files ending in .rb. Specifically, extensions written in C are stored in files ending with .so or .dll. To keep the process transparent-that is, to save you the trouble of knowing whether the extension you want uses a .rb file or not-Ruby accepts a bareword...

Comment: ...and then does some automatic file-searching and trying out of possible filenames until it finds the file corresponding to the extension you have requested.

Comment: _I'm wondering about the distinction between the word "load" and the word "executes"_ In ruby, there is no such distinction. Might help you to read my explanation here: http://www.apeth.com/rubyIntro/justenoughruby.html#definingamoduleisexecutablecode

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The file is always executed.

In Ruby there is no such thing as loading a file without executing it. Everything is a statement in Ruby and has to be executed. Even `class` and `def` are just statements.

To illustrate this here's a silly example

```
class Mystery < [Array, Object, String, Fixnum].sample
  ...
end
```

This creates a class with a random superclass. Just to illustrate that Ruby has no declarations but executable statements only.

So there is no such thing as not executing a Ruby file. The difference between `load` and `require` is as you described, the latter keeps track of all loaded files to avoid reloading them.

---

PS, and another example

```
ruby --dump insns -e 'def example; end'
== disasm: <RubyVM::InstructionSequence:<main>@-e>======================
0000 trace            1                                               (   1)
0002 putspecialobject 1
0004 putspecialobject 2
0006 putobject        :example
0008 putiseq          example
0010 opt_send_without_block <callinfo!mid:core#define_method, argc:3, ARGS_SIMPLE>
0012 leave            
== disasm: <RubyVM::InstructionSequence:example@-e>=====================
0000 trace            8                                               (   1)
0002 putnil           
0003 trace            16                                              (   1)
0005 leave
```

As you can see `def example; end` is a statement and internally calls the `define_method` method. So `def` is just syntactic sugar for a method call.

Comment: To add an example to "Ruby has no declarations but executable statements only", in Rails 5 each migration inherit from `ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]`. This once seemed magic to me, but it turns out that `ActiveRecord::Migration.[](5.0)` returns a class in runtime. That simple.

Comment: Fun fact: everything is not only an executable statement, but it also returns something. Well, "something" can be `nil`, but it is still something: `class Foo; end.nil?` will return "true".

Comment: And `class Foo; 42 end #=> 42` (the value of a class definition is the value of the last expression evaluated inside the definition).